# Replace text and background color of a word document

Tags: r, ms-word, officer

I'd like to create a template with tags which are highlighted. The tags should be replaced with some data with `R`. I have highlighted text in the [template file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qHnuj10aAY_8pmn50PClyi1-Mrlu6qpc/view) and want a blank background in the output file.

I've tried `officer` because that seems to be the most mature `R`-package for manipulating `word` documents. I've tried the `body_replace_all_text` and the `body_replace_text_at_bkm` function but neither seems to provide options to change the formatting.

I am completely open to a different approach. The hard requirements are that the [template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qHnuj10aAY_8pmn50PClyi1-Mrlu6qpc/view) and the output file must be editable by non-technical co-worker (thus a word document) and the input fields in the template must be somehow highlighted. That means if a co-worker manually edit the [template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qHnuj10aAY_8pmn50PClyi1-Mrlu6qpc/view) he wouldn't miss any tags.

**Code**

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

template <- read_docx("template.docx")

pattern <- "<tags>"
replacement <- "tags"
template <- template %>%
  body_replace_all_text(pattern, replacement)

pattern <- "<color.*?/color>"
replacement <- "yellow"
template <- template %>%
  body_replace_all_text(pattern, replacement)

print(template, target = "output.docx")
```

**template.docx**

[image: template.docx]

**output.docx**

[image]

**desired_output.docx**

[image]

**Edit**

Solved that problem by monkey-patching the `officer` package. It's kind of hacky so I'm still open for a cleaner solution.

```
replace_all_text.custom = function( oldValue, newValue, onlyAtCursor=TRUE, warn = TRUE, ... ) {

  oldValue <- enc2utf8(oldValue)
  newValue <- enc2utf8(newValue)

  replacement_count <- 0

  base_node <- if (onlyAtCursor) self$get_at_cursor() else self$get()

  # For each matching text node...
  for (text_node in xml_find_all(base_node, ".//w:t")) {
    # ...if it contains the oldValue...
    if (grepl(oldValue, xml_text(text_node), ...)) {
      replacement_count <- replacement_count + 1
      # Replace the node text with the newValue.
      xml_text(text_node) <- gsub(oldValue, newValue, xml_text(text_node), ...)
      # remove background color
      xml_remove(xml_find_all(text_node, "..//w:highlight"))
    }
  }

  # Alert the user if no replacements were made.
  if (replacement_count == 0 && warn) {
    search_zone_text <- if (onlyAtCursor) "at the cursor." else "in the document."
    warning("Found 0 instances of '", oldValue, "' ", search_zone_text)
  }

  self
}

docx_part.custom <- officer:::docx_part
docx_part.custom$public_methods$replace_all_text <- replace_all_text.custom

assignInNamespace("docx_part", docx_part.custom, ns = "officer")
```

Comment: It doesn't give me yellow in my system. Are you using tracked changes by any chance?

Comment: Just a plain docx-file. I've shared it for you: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qHnuj10aAY_8pmn50PClyi1-Mrlu6qpc/view

Comment: Using Microsoft Word 2013, I still don't get any background color, have you tested it outside Google Docs? I see there is a `fp_text` option in the Officer package, that has a few color options [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/officer.pdf) (pdf - see pg 33).

Comment: I guess you could just copy/paste the text in a new document and color it by yourself. Don't get `fp_text` to work with `body_replace_all_text`.

Comment: I see what you mean now, you have highlighted them in the doc and then want the highlight removed in output. I thought you meant that the tags were coming out yellow as a result of the code. I have no idea....

Comment: Jepp, sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: You might want to edit the question to read something like: "I have highlighted text in the input and want a blank background in the output"

Comment: I am afraid this can not be done with `body_replace_all_text` that only replace text, not formatting properties. Maybe bookmarks and function `body_replace_at` would be better here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated my question, please have look.